# remote objects returning another remote objects in python's RPC world

Tags: python, rpc

I am basically familiar with RPC solutions available in Python: XML-RPC and Pyro. I can make an remote object by binding it on the server-side and then I can get proxy object on the client side on which I can operate. When I call some method on remote object e.g. proxy.get_file() then the rpc mechanism tries to serialize a resultant object (a file in this case). This is usually expected behavior, but what I need is to get a file object as another remote proxy object instead of getting it transferred to client side:

```
afile_proxy = proxy.get_file()
```

Instead of:

```
afile = proxy.get_file()
```

I could rebind this object on server-side and handle such case on the client side but this would require some boiler-plate code. Is there a mechanism/library that would do this for me? It could for example keep objects remote until they are primitive ones.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a library that does exactly what I need: RPyC. From [intro](http://rpyc.wikidot.com/theory):

- simple, immutable python objects (like strings, integers, tuples, etc.) are passed by value, meaning the value itself is passed to the other side.
- all other objects are passed by reference, meaning a "reference" to the object is passed to the other side. This allows changes applied on the referenced object to be reflected on the actual object.

Anyway, thanks for pointing out a 'reference' term. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am involved in developing a new remote-object interaction framework [Versile Python](https://versile.com/products/vpy/) (VPy) which performs similar functions as the ones you have listed. VPy is in development with the current releases primarily intended for testing, however feel free to take a look.

There are two ways you could perform the type of remote I/O you are describing with VPy. One is to use remote [native object](https://versile.com/doc/vpy/current/library/vse/native.html) references to e.g. file objects similar to Pyro/RPyC and access those objects similar to if they were local.

Another option is to use the VPy remote [stream](https://versile.com/doc/vpy/current/library/vse/stream.html) framework which is quite flexible and can be configured to perform bi-directional streaming and operations such as remotely repositioning or truncating the stream. The second approach has the advantage it enables asynchronous I/O plus the stream framework splits up data transmission in order to reduce the effects of round-trip latency.

Answer (score 0):

```
afile_proxy = proxy.get_file_proxy()
```

And define in the API what a `FileProxy` object is. It all depends on what the client needs to do with the proxy. Ge the name? Delete it? Get its contents?

You could even get away with a reference (a URL, maybe) if all you want is to keep track of something you want to process later. It's what's done on the web with all embedded content, like images.